# Are Will Daniels and Grant Ward Inhumans?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Since Hive can only take control of Inhumans brains was Will Daniels and Grant Ward inhumans since he took their body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr**: No, Hive can only possess normal human corpses, but can only mentally control living Inhumans.

---

As I understand it, Hive's power allows it to do three different things:

### Reanimate A Corpse

Hive has the ability to "infect" the body of a dead person, provided they are not an Inhuman. At one point, Malick is concerned with Ward's degenerating body and offers Hive one of his Inhumans as a replacement, and Hive explains that it wouldn't work.

HYDRA sent a long list of people to Maveth to "rescue" Hive, and it possessed most of them, but there's little chance any of them were Inhumans. This was well before the Terrigenesis bomb, and coming across Inhumans was a difficult process for them. So, guys like Will and Grant were just regular people.

### Digest A Body

Hive appears to be made up of a huge multitude of smaller cells or particles or something, and can expel them from its host body to infect nearby living people. It can then drain the life out of those victims from the inside, and transfer that energy back to itself. This is how Hive rejuvenates Grant's corpse with Malick's hostages.

I don't believe all of those victims were Inhumans (again, given how hard it was for Malick to find one, let alone a half-dozen.)

### Inhuman Hive Mind

Hive can also infect the brains of living Inhumans, somehow joining them to its Hive Mind. They don't become zombies or drones or anything like that -- they appear to have full control over their own actions. But they now implicitly share the thoughts and desires of Hive, so their actions are always those that benefit Hive, even over their own needs.

Answer (score 4):

No, they were human.

From what I understand, you are confusing two different processes...

Inhumans are attracted to Hive and he infects them with his parasites... but he generally wants to protect them and use them.

Taking over and controlling a body, though, seems to be something he does with humans specifically, along with consuming them to restore his condition.

The people sent through the monolith by HYDRA were most certainly humans... there's no way for them to have known what inhumans were at the time, considering that they don't even understand what Hive wants at all.